# How to know where the requests come from to my VF page?

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I have a public contactus page(VF page that is hosted using SF sites). I am displaying that contactus page on multiple websites using iFrame. Now the question is that i want to know where the requests come from to my contactus page?

Answer (score 1):

I would interrogate the headers and request parameters, try to find the host or User-Agent request header, which might indicate the source of the HTTP Request.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_pagereference.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you want really good detailed statistics go with something like Google Analytics as Mohith suggested. But that's not really a native SFDC solution, and if you're looking for something that actually affects the way your apex runs based on where the request came from you're going to need something more integrated.

In that case I'd reccomend looking at the request's [Referer header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer). This header's value will tell you what page, if any, sent the user to this one. It's not 100% tamper proof as there are browser extensions that can allow faking this, but it's probably the best you're going to get.

You can get the value of this in apex with:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Referer');
```

Comment: The VF page looks to be sitting in iframes on numerous pages and Ashok wants to know, when user submits, from within which page was the VF page submitted. Does this still hold for investigating the referer? I thought would show you the page that brought you to the page that has the iframe, ie the "previous" page.

Answer (score 1):

To do it programatically from the controller, you can call this method:

ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Referer');

Which obtains the standard Referer header:  http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z14

This is used by Google analytics too and all technology which tracks origins of clicks

Answer (score 0):

https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/sites_analytics_tracking_code.htm

This functionality only can be achieved through google analytics.Google analytics has to be integrated .Its a Javascript that google provides and salesforce sites supports

http://adnsandbox.com/df08/sites_integrating_google_analytics.pdf

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Force-com-Sites/Integrate-Salesforce-with-Google-Analytics/td-p/362689

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Force-com-Sites/Can-the-out-of-the-box-Google-Analytics-track-Force-com-Site/td-p/168008

Few blogs above you may want to look at